# How to Make Containers 'Fluid'

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't find anything on here relating to my problem. I am wanting to know to know how to make these containers feel 'fluid'. I don't know what I need to do to make these containers be the same distance apart.

[What it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY1fm.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjftO.png)

You can see that what I have currently is that sometimes it is on its own row and other times it has to wait until the row is over.

Here is the body code:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1 style="color:white;"><b>Dashboard</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" src="'.$link.'"></iframe></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" src="'.$link.'"></iframe></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" src="'.$link.'"></iframe></div>
    </div>
```

My question is: **How do I  make this 'fluid' without waiting for the next row to fill?**

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please provide your code so far you have tried which will be helpful to give you a solution

Comment: There is not layout method in CSS to achieve what you want (except CSS column layout, which will probably result in an unwanted div order). Google **masonry**.

Answer (score 1):

Masonry grid layout is the solution for your issue. Visit below link and solve your problem. Let me know if you need any help. Thanks

[Masonry Grid url](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: How would I use that with responsive iframes? I can set it only to a set height

Comment: @MarkMueller, could you send me your code in a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to use "container-fluid" from bootsrap.

### Bootstrap has a class named "container-fluid" that fills one row. 100% width.

[Boostrap grids](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)